# Circular dependency detected while autoloading constant DeviseController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

Devise Gemを利用したユーザ認証システムを作成しています。
トップページから /user/sign_in へアクセスしようとすると、タイトルのようなエラーメッセージが出ます。
詳細は、下記の画像の通りです。

[image: rails error message]

Stackoverflowの英語版サイトで調べ、autoloadingが問題であるという指摘を発見しましたが、該当するファイルがなく、異なるところに原因があるように思えます。
何が問題か検討がつかないので、ご教示願いたいです。

Comment: 状況がわからないので `routes.rb` やその他該当しそうなファイルの設定等教えていただければより詳細にアドバイス出来るかと思います。先程devise gemを使って同様のことをしたのですがこのようなエラーにはならなかったのでどこかの設定でうまくいっていないのだと考えられるので。

Comment: お返事ありがとうございます。こちら、config/initializers/devise.rb の
config.parent_controller = 'DeviseController'が有効になっていたために起きていたエラーだと判明しました。@DaikiTagami 様は実際にGemのインストール等を行なってご確認いただき大変ありがとうございました。

Comment: 解決したようでよかったです。お疲れ様でした。